# git merge in wrong folder

Tags: git, github, merge, git-subtree

I have `mainProject` on git, with a `shared library`.
This `shared library` is also in `subProject`.

**my workflow**

I start my project by cloning the project and create a branch :

```
git clone https://github.com/user/mainProject.git main-project
git checkout -b fix
```

I worked on my `mainProject`, and added a awesomeClass.php in the folder `lib/` (the root of the `shared library`)

**The new file structure:**

```
/index.php 
/page1.php
/lib/form/contact.php
/lib/awesomeClass.php*
```

*=new

after this I add and commit my changes.

```
git add lib/awesomeClass.php
git commit -m "added new awesome class that will blow your mind"
```

Add the remote location of the `shared library`, fetch it and connect remote to local branch

```
git remote add sharedlib https://github.com/user/sharedlib.git
git fetch sharedlib
git checkout -b sharedlib sharedlib/master
```

this switches my branch to `sharedlib` where I try to merge my changes to, to get the same changes of the `shared library` to my subProject.

```
 git merge --squash -s subtree --no-commit fix
```

This is where it goes wrong, The file structure was(seen from `sharedlib` branch perspective):

```
/lib/form/contact.php
/lib/awesomeClass.php
```

after merge :

```
/lib/form/index.php*
/lib/form/page1.php*
/lib/form/lib/form/contact.php*
/lib/form/lib/awesomeClass.php*

/lib/form/contact.php
/lib/awesomeClass.php
```

*=new

Can anyone explain how I can merge only the `shared library` and not the full `mainProject` into a wrong folder? 
Thanks!

Comment: Why does `sharedLib` has all its files under a `lib` folder? Should not that be only present in `mainProject` in order to separate `sharedLib` from the rest of the repository content?

Comment: Not sure either how you are handling your `sharedLib`, but just in case this article explains one possible strategy: http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-7.html

Comment: I used this: [Nested libraries submerge](http://typecastexception.com/post/2013/03/16/Managing-Nested-Libraries-Using-the-GIT-Subtree-Merge-Workflow.aspx). this article works only once. After the first merge/update of the `sharedLib`, It will just merge/update to a wrong folder. for example. like the above explanation in the folder `lib/form` instead of just `lib/`.. I tried your article but the same happens at the merge step.

Answer (score 0):

There is some complex workflow you're following regarding the subtree merge strategy but this is out-dated and it's much simpler these days.

What you're looking for is the [**contrib command git-subtree**](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt), which comes complete with a split feature to extract the changes from the main project specifically relevant to that sub-directory so that you can merge them back upstream to the subproject.

Comment: I did see this, but finally found a solution for this. I just made a workflow without a subtree. I symlinked the folder into the project and put it in the gitignore. This is much easier and safer.

Comment: I don't think I agree with either of those, git subtree is pretty easy, and it's much safer in that you have a history of working state, instead of 2 projects which will be maintained independently, you'll have more risk when trying to roll back to a certain point in time. Subtree gives you the ease of having all the subproject files right there in the super project, that's about as easy as it gets.